# В моей winform не работает проверка if и сase

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, clr

У меня имеется задача - написать конвертер фото.
Я решил использовать **Image.FromFile Method**.
Процесс программы таков:

1. Пользователь выбирает в comboBox нужный формат из 5 представленных
2. Нажимает кнопку "конвертировать". Ему открывается проводник и он выбирает пикчу
3. Конвертация

Я столкнулся с проблемой что у меня не работает проверка что именно в ComboBox пользователь выбрал, срабатывает либо else либо же default(код ниже). Я пытался переделать через чекбоксы, if- результат тот же.

```
private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

public:
        String^ p;
    System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
        openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
        p = openFileDialog1->SafeFileName;
        Image^ image = Image::FromFile("C:/Users/Kisik/source/repos/Project2/Project2/"+p); 

        switch (comboBox1->SelectedIndex)
        {
        case 0:
            MessageBox::Show("0");
            image->Save("new_pic.jpeg", ImageFormat::Jpeg);
            break;
        case 1:
            MessageBox::Show("1");
            image->Save("new_pic.png", ImageFormat::Png);
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox::Show("er");
            break;
        }
```

Исходники: https://fex.net/ru/s/zxxpvdt

Но стоит учитывать что путь в строчке 171 не относительный и прога не будет работать пока вы не поменяете на свой путь, я еще не сделал эту чать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в InitializeComponent()
Именно она красовалась в функции MyForm_Load(). Как выяснилось после удаления проблема ушла.
Буду читать про нее документацию